# fraction class increment operator overloading explained

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword, increment, fractions

I've given this a lot of thought (honestly) - since last semester. And I'm still not entirely sure what is going on here. Would anyone be able to help and enlighten me?  I'm ok with the pre/postfix difference. It's how the hell the fraction is being incremented which is confusing the hell out me

take the prefix example for instance.
So if I had a fraction which was 2/4 would that increase to 3/4? Because when I look at numer += denom, it makes me think that it will return 2+2+4, which is 8.

```
// prefix increment operator
fraction& fraction::operator++() {
    numer += denom;
    return *this;
}

// postfix increment operator
fraction fraction::operator++(int) {        // Note dummy int argument
    fraction temp(*this);
    ++*this;                            // call the prefix operator
    return temp;
```

thanks heaps in advance :)

Comment: Why 2+2+4? `numer` is 2 and `denom` is 4. Therefore, `numer += denom;` makes `numer` 6.

Answer (score 3):

The prefix function would spell out to

```
numer = numer + denom;
```

so in case of `2/4` it would be `numer = 2 + 4 = 6` so the result would be `6/4` (since denom remains unchanged). Since `n/n = 1` for all integers (except `0`), `(a+n)/n` will always be an increase by `1`.

The postfix version uses the prefix version to do the calculation explained above.

Comment: You might point out explicitly that this is the equivalent of adding `1` to the number.  (At least for positive numbers; I have my doubts as to whether the algorithm works if `denom` is negative.)

Comment: @JamesKanze True. But I'd expect most fraction implementations to store the sign in the numerator only.

Comment: @JamesKanze Thanks for the suggestion, adopted it.

Comment: @Angew I would expect most fraction implementations to "normalize" the representation, with no common denominators, and the sign in the numerator only.  But since the example given is 2/4, which is not normalized, I'm not sure, and I thought it worth pointing out.

Comment: @JamesKanze Why wouldn't the algorithm work if `denom` is negative? `(a+n)/n = a/n + n/n = a/n + 1`, or at a concrete example `1/(-2)++ = (1+(-2))/(-2) = (-1)/(-2) = 1/2`

Comment: @nijansen Good point.  Maybe it would work.  It just wasn't as obvious as when `denom` is positive.